# convert Array to csv php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title
            [1] => Date
            [2] =>  Text
            [3] =>  Category
            [4] => ID
            [5] => img

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 1
            [1] => 2005-11-20
            [2] => "Text article"
            [3] => News
            [4] => 100
            [5] => <img scr="">
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
           [0] => title 2
            [1] => 2005-11-21
            [2] => "Text article"
            [3] => News
            [4] => 101
            [5] => <img scr="">
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 3
            [1] => 2005-11-22
            [2] => "Text article"
            [3] => News
            [4] => 102
            [5] => <img scr="">

}}
```

How can I convert this to a CSV file?

Answer (score 5):

You should use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function.

> fputcsv — Format line as CSV and write to file pointer

Below example is given in the link.

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($array as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this php function [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You will have to need [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to achieve this.